# How to get and set post meta for core/navigation-link?

Tags: menus, block-editor, navigation

I'm extending a plugin that updated nav menu items with post meta data. This was previously done via Appearance>Menus and Appearance>Customize using `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields` and `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields_customize_template` actions. Extra fields were shown (boolean, numeric, dropdowns) for menu items and stored in post meta. My goal is now to extend the `core/navigation-link` block with some attributes (boolean and numeric values) so that the same can be achieved via the new FSE/blocks editor. These attributes should, therefore, be stored in the meta data, so that no matter via which route you go, the same data is stored.

Via the old Appearance>Menus (and Appearance>Customize), we had PHP functions `get_post_meta` and `update_post_meta`. This only required the menu item ID in order to update meta data for a navigation item.

Now, if I'm not mistaken, the same can be achieved in FSE/Blocks with the `useEntityProp` method. This method takes four parameters: kind,  name, prop, ID.

I can't however find a reference or documentation on which parameters to supply in case of nav menu items (which is now the `core/navigation-link` block).

I've found this source https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/core-data/src/entities.js#L186 but supplying kind=`root` and name=`menuItem` to the method returns null meta data.

```
const [meta, updateMeta] = useEntityProp('root', 'menuItem', 'meta', props.attributes.id); // meta is null
```

The custom control is rendered correctly and using `setAttribute` works fine. But how do I get and set the post meta data for nav menu items via this route?

```
const myExtraControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {
        // meta is returned null:
        const [meta, updateMeta] = useEntityProp('root', 'menuItem', 'meta', props.attributes.id);
        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit key="edit" {...props} />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <ToggleControl
                        label={wp.i18n.__('Some boolean', 'my-plugin')}
                        checked={!!meta.someboolean}
                        onChange={(newval) => updateMeta({ ...meta, someboolean: newVal })}
                    />
                </InspectorControls>
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'withMyPluginControls');

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'my-plugin/my-block',
    myExtraControls 
);
```

Still `meta` object returns `undefined`. Entire object is undefined, no fields contained in there.

```
const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', 'menuItem', 'meta', props.attributes.id );
console.log('meta', meta); // undefined
```

As suggested, below you may find the full code to block JSX and a code snippet showing the assets registration and the `register_meta` calls.

core_navigation_link_block.jsx: https://gist.github.com/DianaKoenraadt/3358ae2e492a2757e8f9df563c30179d

core_navigation_link_plugin.php:
https://gist.github.com/DianaKoenraadt/1d87b5179d7eecd2eeb7b646aee1577f

Comment: can you edit your question to make it clearer? The first paragraph doesn't make sense and is missing a lot of context, yet the rest of the question isn't understandable without this. What UI are you trying to implement that requires this? Where is the code being executed? Is this inside another block? A store subscriber? Without knowing the context/location of where you tried to use `useEntityProp` it's not possible to tell you how to retrieve the menu ID, there just isn't enough information

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your reply, I've updated the question

Comment: I see, given the original menu UI from before the customizer is still there and in many ways more canonical than the customizer menu UI, wouldn't it make more sense to focus on that? Block based menu UI is something that's never been finalised and what you're trying to modify probably doesn't represent what you think it represents, or works the way you thought it did.

Comment: case in point, if you save the post, only the top level nav block is saved, the nav link blocks you're trying to modify only exist inside the editor

Comment: Are you sure that your construction actually runs? Using the name of the class as the name of the constructor is a C++ thing not really a PHP thing and something that happened in ancient PHP. Modern PHP uses `function __construct(`

Comment: Ignore that. I have a __construct, I just cut out 1000+ loc for this gist. It runs, I guarantee you, I have 20+ other things I hook up

Comment: Could it be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310854/wordpress-useentityprop-returns-undefined

Comment: if what the answer suggests fixed it for you then yes, if it doesn't then no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a menu item in a *classic menu*, then yes, you could use `useEntityProp` to get and set the menu item's post meta, except that the post type is actually `nav_menu_item` and that you would need to manually add *custom fields support* to that post type.

```js
const navMenuItemId     = 123;
const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', 'nav_menu_item', 'meta', navMenuItemId );
```

However, as for the `core/navigation-link` block, the `props.attributes.id` value is not actually the (classic) menu item's post ID. It is instead the database ID, if any, of the linked resource, e.g. a Page ID if the resource was a Page at `https://example.com/sample-page`.

It should also be noted that the parent block, namely `core/navigation`, uses a *non-public* custom post type named `wp_navigation`, and the menu items (which are inner blocks of the Navigation block) are stored in the **post content** of a Navigation post (i.e. post of the `wp_navigation` type), and when a Navigation block is added to a post, the generated block markup would look like `<!-- wp:navigation {"ref":502} /-->` whereby `502` is the ID of a Navigation post.

- You can edit/view the post by navigating to `<your site URL>/wp-admin/site-editor.php?postId=502&postType=wp_navigation&canvas=edit`.
- Sample admin screen:

  [image: Screenshot]

Having said all that, it is unfortunately not possible to get the classic menu item's post ID from the Navigation Link block's markup, but these might help:

- You can use the [`blocks.registerBlockType` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype) to add `someboolean` (and your other attributes) **as attributes** of the Navigation Link block, which means your attributes will be saved in the post content instead.
- The above filter can also be used to add the `ref` attribute of the Navigation block as a [context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) which can be consumed by the Navigation Link block.

  That way, you can, if you want to, get and set the Navigation post's meta. But just like the `nav_menu_item` post type, you will need to manually add custom fields support to the `wp_navigation` post type.
- There's a block filter named `blocks.navigation.__unstableMenuItemsToBlocks` which can be used to get the menu item's post ID, but only when a classic menu is imported via the editor. [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjyDE.png)

  ```js
  wp.hooks.addFilter(
      'blocks.navigation.__unstableMenuItemsToBlocks',
      'my-plugin/on-import-classic-menu',
      ( blocks, menuItems ) => {
          console.log( blocks, menuItems );
          /*
           * `blocks` is an object with 2 items, i.e. `innerBlocks` and `mapping`.
           * `mapping` is an object like so:
              {
                  // Each row is "<menu item's post ID>": "<block's clientId>", and
                  // corresponds to a `core/navigation-link` block.
                  "303": "b6fb470c-cc9a-4cd1-b93a-dbda6d705bde",
                  "304": "a7ee7b72-d5fa-4b64-9ea6-e3c64c89ee05",
                  "306": "aa9aa567-1084-4dc5-9f2b-b216eb321576",
                  "486": "99346d86-bbc9-497c-9fea-7e85401ad287"
              }
          */

          return blocks;
      }
  );
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

```js
        const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', 'menuItem', 'meta', postId );
```

Importantly, `menuItem` is a post type, not a top level object type. You would only use `root` if you wanted to list all post types for example, or all taxonomies ( rather than posts/terms, e.g. `'post', 'page', etc...` ).

If no `postId` is provided it will assume the currently edited post.

Then you can retrieve registered post `meta` like this:

```js
const { testmeta } = meta;
```

And use `setMeta( { testmeta: newvalue })` in `useEffect` and event handlers.

However keep in mind that:

- the meta you're trying to set has to be registered via `register_meta` or it won't appear in the REST API and the block editor can't see/write it.
- the nav menu UI changes a lot and shouldn't be considered finalised
- *At the time of writing the original menus page under appearance is still a more reliable and more canonical source for nav menu editing than both the customizer and the site editor at the moment.* There's a chance what you build will still break in a future update.

Comment: Can you explain "has to be registered"? How and where would I register my new meta fields in this new WoW

Comment: I'll try later this week to omit the fourth parameter as you suggest, and see if that does return a meta object

Comment: Using `register_meta`, the same as registering a setting/option, or a custom post type. Without this the REST API doesn't know about your post meta, what it should be called, who can read/write to it, and what type of values to expect. If it's not in the REST API then gutenberg will be unaware.

Comment: as for the proper use of `useEntityProp`, the mistake was that you used `root` as the first parameter, when it should have been `postType`. `root` would have been appropriate if you weren't fetching posts but rather a list of the post types themselves, e.g. `"post", "page",etc..`

Comment: I've made some edits

Comment: Unfortunately, the meta object still returns undefined. (I'm using the only id that is available to me, which is props.attributes.id)

Comment: I've set a bounty on the question, since so far meta is always undefined for me. Something must be missing here

Comment: @Diana you've described that you registered meta and it did not show up but all you've shared is a description, there could be obvious mistakes you're unaware of. Edit your question to include _everything_, any back and forth discussion can severely reduce the chances of a good answer, especially if you keep that information hidden in comments like this, or just describe using words instead of sharing directly

Comment: fair enough, I've added two gists, hopefully that helps

Comment: if you can put it directly in your question, it needs to be self contained. I also left a note about constructors in a comment on the question, I suspect your registration code never runs as you've put a C++ style constructor in your class rather than using a normal `__construct` name, see the note here on old style constructors https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Ignore that. I have a __construct, I just cut out 1000+ loc for this gist. It runs, I guarantee you, I have 20+ other things I hook up